# How do I change grid-template-columns style with JS?

Tags: javascript, css

this is the class I'm trying to change in my CSS file.

```
.screen{
margin-top: 0%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 75%;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
}
```

I assign a size variable and then I assume I can use something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('screen').style = "grid-template-columns: repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"
```

but cannot get it to work. :(

Comment: please share your html

Answer (score 0):

You Simply do the following :

```
document.getElementById("yourdivision").style.gridTemplateColumns = "50px 50px 50px";
```

Or :

```
document.getElementById("yourdivision").style.gridTemplateColumns = "1fr 1fr 1fr";
```

Answer (score -1):

this is because `document.getElementsByClassName('screen')` returns an array so try using this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('screen')[0].style
```